# Getting stray semicolon error in SV interface

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am writing a code for up down counter by using system verilog for that I have build my interface but it gives me a error stating that Illegal declaration after the statement near line '11'. Declarations must precede statements. Look for stray semicolons.

```
interface my_cnt_if(input bit clk);
     logic [3:0]dta_in;
     logic [3:0]cnt;
     logic load;
     logic u_d;
     logic rstn;

     clocking de_cb@(posedge clk);
       default input #1 output #2;
       output din;
       output load;
       output u_d;
     endclocking

     clocking me_cb@(posedge clk);
       default input #1 output #2;
       input din;
       input load;
       input u_d;
     endclocking

    clocking mr_cb@(posedge clk);
      default input #1 output #2;
      input cnt;
     endclocking        
   
     modport DV(clocking de_cb);
     modport MW(clocking me_cb);
     modport MR(clocking mr_cb);
endinterface
```

I this code I am getting error stating that Illegal declaration after the statement near line '11'. Declarations must precede statements. Look for stray semicolons. can someone please help me to find what is actually wrong here.

Comment: I'm not getting the same error as you are. I'm getting a message `din` not declared. That seems to be a typo. Can you tell us which is line 11?

Answer (score 0):

All of the signals in your clocking blocks should have corresponding signals in the interface as well. The compiler doesn't recognize the signal "din" in the clocking blocks. I'm guessing you meant to name them "dta_in" instead of "din.

Comment: I changed that in my code still the error exists

Answer (score 0):

Both code samples in this answer compile in four simulators on eda playground with no errors.

The reason for the error in the post is stated in a previous answer.

Restating here is different words: Each `wire` in a `clocking` block must correspond to a same named `wire` in the `interface` which contains the clocking block; the names must be the identical.

In the original question, the `interface` name dta_in does not match the name d_in for the two `clocking` blocks.

This version uses d_in as the common name.

```
   interface my_cnt_if(input bit clk);
      
     logic [3:0]d_in;
     logic [3:0]cnt;
     logic load;
     logic u_d;
     logic rstn;
    
     clocking de_cb @(posedge clk);
       default input #1 output #1;
       output d_in;
       output load;
       output u_d;
     endclocking
    
     clocking me_cb@(posedge clk);
       default input #1 output #1;
       input d_in;
       input load;
       input u_d;
     endclocking
    
     clocking mr_cb@(posedge clk);
      default input #1 output #1;
      input cnt;
     endclocking  
    
     modport DV(clocking de_cb);
     modport MW(clocking me_cb);
     modport MR(clocking mr_cb);

   endinterface
```

The other name (dta_in) can also be used:

```
   interface my_cnt_if(input bit clk);
      
     logic [3:0]dta_in;
     logic [3:0]cnt;
     logic load;
     logic u_d;
     logic rstn;
    
     clocking de_cb @(posedge clk);
       default input #1 output #1;
       output dta_in;
       output load;
       output u_d;
     endclocking
    
     clocking me_cb@(posedge clk);
       default input #1 output #1;
       input dta_in;
       input load;
       input u_d;
     endclocking
    
    clocking mr_cb@(posedge clk);
      default input #1 output #1;
      input cnt;
     endclocking        
    
     modport DV(clocking de_cb);
     modport MW(clocking me_cb);
     modport MR(clocking mr_cb);
           
   endinterface
```